# Existing Managed accounts is not changable

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, configuration-wizard

When I want to use existing managed account in Configuration wizard --> Launch the farm Configuration wizard--> Start the wizard --> Use existing managed account is not changeable. In this page, all items are locked.

How can I change to an editable one?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't ever use Config Wizard! :)

If you already have Service Applications, than you cannot remove them through wizard (they'll be grayed out and you cannot remove selection).
As it's stated on wizard page: "You cannot change the service account in this wizard because a default account has already been created for this farm. You can change the accounts used for each service from the Configure Service Accounts page in the Security section of the central administration site."

You can go to "Security" -> "Configure service accounts" ( /_admin/FarmCredentialManagement.aspx ) and change account for "Service Application Pool - SharePoint Web Services Default".
This'll change the default service account on wizard page.